# plist won't delete programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am attempting to create a 'start over' function in an iPhone application, but I cannot get a plist file to delete with the following code

```
- (IBAction)startOver:(id)sender {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:@"data.plist" error:NULL];

    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"welcome"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can anybody see why?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the file. Where did you save it?

Comment: I used the method -(NSString *)getFilePath{
    NSArray *files = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[files objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you save `data.plist` in the `Documents` directory, then you do this:

```
- (NSString *)getFilePath {
    NSArray *files = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[files objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
}

- (IBAction)startOver:(id)sender {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *path = [self getFilePath];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];

    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"welcome"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```